# Inno Setup Set Password based on external information

Tags: inno-setup

My setup installer downloads an ini file and fetches a value from it.  I want to use this value as the password for the installer.

I can fetch the file and fetch the value, but I can't figure out how to set the password.  I tried this, but pascal doesn't know the variable for 'password'

```
 thispassword := getinistring('installer','key','George', expandconstant('{tmp}\' + inifilename) );
 TPasswordEdit.password := thispassword;
```

Actually, I think `TPasswordEdit` is just the edit box controls, anyway.  But I've tried `TPasswordEdit.text` too.  (`password` is a boolean anyway)

Can I even change the password via code?

Comment: What is `TPasswordEdit` ? Is that a `TNewEdit` control that you've created, or something else ?

Comment: I found `TPasswordEdit` in the "Support Classes Reference" for Pascal Scripting in the Inno Setup docs.  It seems to be a definition of the TCustomEdit class.  No I didn't make it up.

Comment: I'm sorry!  Yes, I mean the setup password that you define in `[setup]`.

Comment: No, I don't want to set the value at compile time.  I want to set it during install time...

Comment: Ah, I think I got it now. Well, to set that pwd. edit box you can use the `WizardForm.PasswordEdit.Text` property, but are you sure that you want to actually prefill that password edit with a value that you read as a plain text from some file ? You should consider using `CheckPassword` event and comparing a SHA-1 hash that you store in your file against the passed `Password` parameter value. If that is for some deployment test purposes, definitely prefer using `/PASSWORD` command line parameter.

Comment: Not quite... That will set the bullets in the text field, but doesn't change the underlying password.

Comment: It does; [`try it`](http://pastebin.com/0jREiDjK) yourself. What is worse, anyone can turn those *bullets* pretty easily into a text if they know how. That's yet another reason why to avoid pre-filling that edit anyway.

Comment: Okay, so I set the default password.  Then I download my file and use `Wizardform.PasswordEdit.Text` to change it.  I can see the correct bullet points, but it doesn't accept the password.  It still only accepts the default password set in the `[setup]` section.

Comment: But that's how it should work. You set the `Password` directive in the `[Setup]` section (and that remains fixed) and Inno Setup then compares what the user enters into that edit box against that directive value. You cannot change that `Password` directive value at runtime. That must be known at compilation time. I think I got closer to your aim. You are trying to download a file with the password which the user then should enter into that password edit box, is that right ? Because if so, there is still the `CheckPassword` event for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't directly answer your question, as it sounds that you actually need something else. I got your aim as that you want to download a file with the password and let the user enter such password to continue the installation. If that is so, I would do it this way (password is `Hello`, case sensitive):

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
; note, that there is no Password defined here, because Password
; is fixed and must be defined at compilation time and cannot be
; used for case I described above

[Code]
const
  Salt = ' world!';

function DownloadPasswordSomehow: string;
begin
  // you will download an SHA-1 hash; this one is "Hello world!"
  Result := 'd3486ae9136e7856bc42212385ea797094475802';
end;

function CheckPassword(Password: String): Boolean;
var
  NetPwd: string;
begin
  // download the password hash somehow, from somewhere
  NetPwd := DownloadPasswordSomehow;
  // and let the setup continue only when the SHA-1 hashed string
  // of the entered password with some salt (password is "Hello",
  // salt is " world!") matches to the downloaded hash
  Result := GetSHA1OfString(Password + Salt) = NetPwd;
end;
```

Comment: Except SHA-1, there are functions for getting MD5 hash strings in Inno Setup, which you can combine, or use repetitively with some strong salt if you want to increase safety a bit. Just note, that everything running on local machine can be disassembled, and sending a password, even hashed through a network will never be absolutely secure. But that is what your requirement, if I got it right of course, never can be.

Comment: Hashing the password is a different issue (but thanks for that).  The problem is that I don't want to use the password set at compilation time.  I want to generate the password 'on the fly' - that is, by using the file that download that will contain the password necessary for the installer to work.  What you showed me in the comments to my question would set the bullets but not the actual password.  But you said it, the password has to be set at compilation time.  So the answer is to create your own dialogue and not to use Innos password window at all.

Comment: Yes, the `Password` directive value must be known at compilation time. But it's not the only way to show and use the built-in password page. The other one is shown in this answer. It shows how to *download* a password which the user then must enter to continue the installation (the `DownloadPasswordSomehow` function is a pseudocode; in real you would put there a code which will return the downloaded password hash string). It is enough to write a handler for the `CheckPassword` to show and override the built-in password page and its verification mechanism (no need for custom page).

Comment: Thanks TLama.  That was the right answer.  I was confusing `CheckPassword` with the Wizard page.  I posted my own code below.

Comment: You're welcome! You may take a look on a similar [`version`](http://pastebin.com/gpu4CKGz) which uses only standard Windows WinHTTP library (uses no external plugin), no files for exchange (the file is downloaded directly into a string variable).

Comment: do you prefer to use the Windows WinHTTP library?  Is that better?  Is there less of a chance of being caught up in Anti-Virus?

Comment: Yes, I would personally prefer WinHTTP before that plugin for this single task. But it's difficult to say that WinHTTP is better. WinHTTP is a Windows API for HTTP communication, whilst that downloader plugin is wrapped around a library which is building and parsing HTTP requests and responses by itself, communicating through a lower level Winsock API. They both do the same on the lowest level. And yes, I would say so. It's more risky to ship an external library (itdownload.dll) and get into trouble with some paranoid antivirus. But I believe it's well known for a while, so it should be fine.

Comment: With that good explanation, my only hangup would be the download progressbar you get with the itd library.  If you don't display the progress of a larger download then the wizard appears to hang.

Comment: That's problematic since you cannot easily create a worker thread where you would download your files. Even when you can use asynchonous mode (that is the 3rd parameter of the [`Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383989(v=vs.85).aspx) method), you have no place to wait for its completion. That would require to use a different WinHTTP API part, the C/C++ functions (which supports also progress callbacks except other extended features).

Answer (score 1):

TLlama had the right answer when he suggested to use `CheckPassword`.  Up till then I thought that was the same as using the Password Wizard Page.  But here is my final working code.

The idea here is to have an installer that only provides one chance for an automatic password.

This allows for different functionality:

1. First, the installer will download a file and use the password contained therein.
2. If the file can't be had, or the password is wrong, the user can always supply it.
3. Finally, there is a master password that can be used by the IT team.

Here is my working code in case anyone comes a-lookin':

```
[Code]
var 
  initialpassword: string;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  // initialize the downloader
  ITD_Init;

  itd_setoption('UI_AllowContinue', '1');
  itd_addfile('http://www.somesite/somefile.txt', expandconstant('{tmp}\myini.ini') );
  itd_downloadafter(wpWelcome);
end;


function CheckPassword(Password: String): Boolean;
var
  returnvalue: boolean;
begin  
  initialpassword := getinistring('installer','key','', expandconstant('{tmp}\myini.ini'));
  result := false;
  if(password = initialpassword)then result := true;
  if(password = 'MasterPassword')then result := true;
  if(password = '')then result := false;
end;
```

Now, I haven't added the hashing yet for the password, but I am going to.